# Leaflet throws an error about html dependency error

Tags: r, leaflet

I just updated R and RStudio and now one of my plots is not working anymore (worked with R 4.1.2):

```
> dput(head(dat))
structure(list(place = c("Firozpur India", "Chandigarh India", 
"Delhi India", "Mumbai India", "Bangalore India", "Shahjahanpur India"
), lon = c(74.6601408124889, 76.7797143, 77.1565959, 72.8773928, 
77.590082, 79.7465629486983), lat = c(30.88510035, 30.7334421, 
28.6600584, 19.0759899, 12.9767936, 27.91263315)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0d580fae0>)


plt <- leaflet(data = dat, options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~lon, ~lat) %>% 
  addScaleBar(position = 'bottomright', 
              options = scaleBarOptions(maxWidth = 200, metric = T, imperial = T)) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels) 


> plt
Error in copyDependencyToDir(dep, libdir, FALSE) : 
  Can't copy dependency files that don't exist: '/var/folders/x1/bvw5ntr53s5f48n1gbqpf6000000gn/T//RtmpnNNM7U/leaflet-providers_1.9.0.js'
```

** Session Info **

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] htmltools_0.5.2   data.table_1.14.2 leaflet_2.1.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_1.5.4       compiler_4.2.0          magrittr_2.0.3         
 [4] R6_2.5.1                fastmap_1.1.0           cli_3.3.0              
 [7] leaflet.providers_1.9.0 tools_4.2.0             curl_4.3.2             
[10] yaml_2.3.5              crosstalk_1.2.0         jsonlite_1.8.0         
[13] digest_0.6.29           rlang_1.0.2
```

I've tried reinstalling the packages - when that didn't work I reinstalled R and RStudio - no luck there either.

Comment: I get this error when trying to run your code:  `Error in addMarkers(., ~lon, ~lat, color = "#003366") :  unused argument (color = "#003366")`.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a relic from what I was trying before I did the updates. Even after removing `color = '#003366'`, I get the same error

Comment: If you don't post code that people can run to see the error, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you with it.